# How to add dropdown in google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, google-forms

I would like to add different dropdown in google form.
If users choose **1** in the first drop-down, then in the second dropdown there will be shown **"Apple, Banna"**.
Users select **2** in the second drop-down, then users can choose **"Orange, Pineapple" **.

I would like to do in google form like this because I have to do a survey. 
[image]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible on Google Forms directly; although, have starred this question to keep an eye out should that not be the case :)